# One way to source data binding in android

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-databinding

Is there any way to implement the "one-way to source" data binding using the android libraries...
to be more specific this pattern is described as follow:

> One Way To Source – This is the mode in which source is updated with the data from the UI. One example which I can think of this scenario
>   is the Login form where we need to send the data from the form to the
>   model class.

so is there any way to do that in android?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used "One-Way-To-Source" data binding myself, and I have the impression that most people use "Two-Way" data binding instead. I think you will be quite happy with two way data binding. Take a look at the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way)